# Why is firebase.auth undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using React and Firebase. I am trying to check, wether the user is authenticated. I have initialized firebase in a firebase config file and therefore import firebase from the file:

```
import { firebase } from './utils/firebase';
```

Inside of this File I imported getAuth and everything else
I then tried to check the logged in Status with the following code:

```
    const[isUserSignedIn, setIsUsersignedIn] = useState(true);

  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if(user) {
      return setIsUsersignedIn(true);
    }
    else{
      setIsUsersignedIn(false);
    }
```

But i receive the following Error:

```
> Uncaught TypeError: _utils_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.firebase.auth is not a function
```

Please help.

Comment: Please edit your question and add complete `'./utils/firebase'` file so we can see the imports. Also is your Firebase version 9?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.